# JPA entity and JAXB conditional serialization

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb, jax-rs

I'm developing a Web Service using JAX-RS, JPA and JAXB.

I'm having a problem to serialize the JPA Entity with JAXB annotations.

Here is the model:

Projeto.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name = "projetos")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Projeto implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idProjeto")
private Long id;

private String nome;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "projeto", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "targets")
@XmlElement(name = "target")
private Collection<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Collection<Target> getTargets() {
    return targets;
}

public void setTargets(Collection<Target> targets) {
    this.targets = targets;
}
}
```

Target.java

```
@Entity(name = "targets")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Target {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="idTarget")
private Long id;

private String nome;

@ManyToOne
@XmlTransient
private Projeto projeto;

@Column(name = "tipo")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TipoTarget tipoTarget;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public TipoTarget getTipoTarget() {
    return tipoTarget;
}

public void setTipoTarget(TipoTarget tipoTarget) {
    this.tipoTarget = tipoTarget;
}

public Projeto getProjeto() {
    return projeto;
}

public void setProjeto(Projeto projeto) {
    this.projeto = projeto;
}
```

Scenario: I want to list all projects and retrieve a project given its ID.

When retrieving a project given an ID, there was no problem.

The problem began when listing all the projects. In this case, i don't want the XML to show the targets, since I'm not going to use that information at this point. In this case, the JPQL running this query is not fetching the targets. When JAXB is trying to serialize the list of "Projetos" to XML, it's throwing a LazyInitializationException.

So, here is the question: how can I annotate my class so it ignores the field if it isn't populated instead of trying to fetch it?

**EDIT 1**

Not sure if i was very clear before, so i'll explain it better.

When i'm searching a project given a ID, i'm fetching the targets in the JPQL query and JAXB is serializing successfully.

When listing all projects, i'm not fetching all targets and i don't want to, since i'm not going to use this info when i'm calling this method. In this moment, i'm getting the LazyInitializationException.

Answer (score 1):

**I fix this problem in this way:**

By replacing JPA annotations from the fields and putting them on the getter methods, JPA doesn't use the fields in its proxies. as a result, JAXB marshaling won't trigger the lazy loaded properties.

Listing all projects don't fetch the targets, so it's ok, but to fetch the targets when you query the project by ID, use this code snippet:

```
    Query q = this.em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Projeto p JOIN FETCH p.targets WHERE p.id = :id");
    q.setParameter("id", projectId);
    Projeto project = (Projeto) q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I replaced the JPA annotations from fields to the getter methods and happened the same problem when listing all projects.  I didn't have a problem when searching a project by it, i already did what your snippet suggests.

Comment: Lazy fetch means the data won't be fetched from the DB. If it already exists in your persistent context it comes into your entity anyway. Are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: I know this and that's what i want. I don't want to fetch the targets when listing all project. The exception is thrown when my JAXB provider is trying to serialize the object. I replaced all JPA and JAXB annotations to getter method e removed the @XmlAccessorType. It didn't work :(

Comment: Are you still struggling to find a solution? I'm very keen to help.

Comment: Still didn't find a solution.

Comment: Why not just to add an extra field to the "Project" class and get it filled with the value of the "targets" in the findById execution path. In this way you can ignore the "Targets" field as a JAXB field; Instead, the new field will be marshaled and the exception will never happen again if the findAll method is called.

Comment: Sorry man, i didn't understand what are you suggesting. My findById execution is working perfectly as you describe. The findAll isn't. I'm seriously considering using a wrapper class (dto) to stop this issue.

Comment: I thought you insisted not to separate Entities from DTOs. If you're gonna add DTO classes to be used by Rest resources, this question doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: And i really don't use DTO. I just don't know what to do anymore.